# I'm looking for a free to use font like Avenir Next with raised superscript for the registered trademark character

Tags: fonts, mac

I'm using Avenir Next for a website. One thing about it is that it renders the registered trademark as superscript. So for example:

```
Extensive Enterprises®
```

The R looks smaller and higher than the other letters. Avenir Next comes included on Macs. Other machines don't have it, so I have fallback fonts. These fallback fonts don't render the R character as superscript, so I'd have to do:

```
Extensive Enterprises<sup>®</sup>
```

This causes a problem because now it doesn't look right on Macs (or other machines that do have Avenir Next).

Can you recommend a free font that raises the ® character in the same way that Avenir Next does? Ideally it would be as similar to Avenir Next as possible.

Comment: Somewhat depend on what software you are using. *Most* layout applications have a shortcut for superscript with no need to insert tags...I would assume you are creating HTML markup... which would means without the markup tags.. even Avenier may **not** be displaying the registration mark as superscript in HTML. (Isn't Avenier an Adobe font inclusion and not Apple? Always thought it was Adobe.)

Comment: Are you looking for a webfont? [Google has quite a number](https://fonts.google.com/?preview.text=Registered%20trade%20mark%C2%AE&preview.text_type=custom), some of which do have ® in a "superscript" position.